# How to get the api test coverage against swagger ui

Tags: rest, api, karate, test-coverage

I would like to get the API test coverage from my karate test scripts against swagger UI or a JSON file. Could anyone guide me on how to get the test coverage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very vague question. I would say just use tags. Maintain a JSON mapping of tags to your custom needs (Swagger or anything else). Write a small program to generate your coverage report from the `Results` object returned from the parallel runner. If you have more specific questions ask a new one.